# How can I unbind a mouseover in jQuery for a TD within a TR?

Tags: jquery

Here is my HTML:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr class="myTr">
        <td>
            CELL 1
        </td>
        <td>
            Cell 2
        </td>
        <td class="notThis">
            Cell 3
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="myTr">
        <td>
            2- CELL 1
        </td>
        <td>
            2- Cell 2
        </td>
        <td>
            2- Cell 3
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="myDiv">CONSOLE</div>
```

And my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready( function() {  
    $(".myTr").mouseover( function() {
        $("#myDiv").html( "OVER" );
    } );
});
```

I want it so that when you mouseover the "notThis" cell, the mouseover doesn't trigger. I have a fiddle set up for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/S7bfH/3/

Thanks

Comment: If you are changing CSS on the mouseover event, it may be easier to just adjust the CSS for td.notThis to appear unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here:

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/S7bfH/6/)

```
    $(".myTr td:not('.notThis')").hover( function() {
        $("#myDiv").html( "ACTIVE" );
    }, function() {
        $("#myDiv").html( "INACTIVE" );        
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop the event propagation; this prevents the event from bubbling up to the ancestor element, where the other handler is bound. Do this with [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation) in a handler bound to the `td` element:

```
$('.notThis').mouseover(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the .not() method for example

```
$(".myTr").not(".notThis").mouseover( function() {
```

Comment: That won't help, because the event was never bound to `.notThis` in the first place. This just binds the handler to all `.myTr` elements that aren't `.notThis` -- which is all of them! The problem is event bubbling, here.