# Onmouseover event on TR tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I added `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events to TR tag, like this:

```
<table cellspacing=0>
    <tr onmouseover="console.log('mouseover');" onmouseout="console.log('mouseout');">
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td>Bar <span>Baz</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Problem is: events are also fired, when mouse is moved from one cell to other; or over span inside cell. I need to determine only those cases, when mouse enters or leaves row.

I also examined `this` for events, it's TR every time - so no nothing helpful for that purpose.

Comment: I think this question is resolved here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332939/how-can-i-unbind-a-mouseover-in-jquery-for-a-td-within-a-tr

Comment: check this out maybe helpful [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/sN8af/1/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I unbind a mouseover in jQuery for a TD within a TR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332939/how-can-i-unbind-a-mouseover-in-jquery-for-a-td-within-a-tr)